# What is "SO Proper"?

Tags: support, terminology

I have heard many people refer to something called "SO Proper", what exactly is this?

Comment: I think the OP of your example question wanted to ask this: "Is SO, a proper place to earn reputation for a good job?"

Comment: Sometimes the main Stack Overflow site is referred to as "SO Proper" here on Meta (kind of like saying "SO Main"), but as @Aziz points out, that's not quite the case here.

Comment: While the example turned out to be a fluke, if you don't know something, you gotta ask. Not sure why you folks are down voting someone simply curious about jargon into oblivion.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proper . See definition 5.  When people refer to "SO proper", it basically means the SO Q/A site itself, rather than chat or meta.SO or some other part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: SO Proper is where we all wear tophats, monocles and speak highly grammatical sentences about programming, old bean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"SO Proper" is typically said in the following contexts:

1. A user asking a question in chat that should probably be composed and asked on Stack Overflow, as that's the 'proper' place to ask non-trivial questions. E.g. "*You should ask that on SO proper ...*"
2. A user asking a similar question as a comment, or an answer to an existing question, though here it's much more common to just say 'proper', or 'properly'.
3. Asking for reference material that would be desirable on Stack Overflow if asked as a 'proper' canonical question and answer. E.g. "*That blog post should be on SO proper!*"

In your example, a few words were left out of the title. It was asking if Stack Overflow was a proper place for something, not really in the context of "SO Proper". However, yes, it is a term that is used semi frequently.

Comment: In this case, "correct", "suitable" etc actually don't have much to do with the definition.  The example i typically see of this usage is "the town proper", which would mean the area strictly within the town limits (specifically excluding the surrounding area, which might otherwise be considered part of the town).